# will_paginate gem throws exception on nil searches

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, lazy-loading, will-paginate, rails-activerecord

I'm seeing exceptions from the `will_paginate` gem when trying to process search results if the results happen to be nil.

Here's the code:

```
@posts = Post.search(query).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
```

So it's easy enough to add in an if statement to make sure that paginate never gets called on nil:

```
if !Post.search(query).nil?
    @posts = Post.search(query).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
end
```

However, imagine that my Post.search(query) returns something like 500,000 posts.

Will_paginate is smart enough to append a `LIMIT` to the SQL query in a lazy fashion, so that the database never has to cough up all 500,000 (only, in this case, 8 per page at a time).

My concern is that the `Post.search(query).nil?` does not have this LIMIT applied to it, and so it may be returning all 500,000 posts, just to determine whether the query is nil!  That seems crazy.

Beyond that concern about querying for the whole 500,000 results, the other disadvantage of the way I'm doing it here is that it involves two separate `Post.search` requests.

Is there a more graceful way to ensure that I can avoid these `paginate was called on nill` errors, without hitting the database more than I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the method `.try` instead of `if !Post.search(query).nil?`

Your code should look something like this:

```
@posts = Post.search(query).try(:paginate, {:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8})
```

PS. `if Post.search(query)` will be enough as well.

Comment: Try is great!  `if Post.search(query)` is a great cleanup of my syntax. But the `try` approach means I can skip that line altogether, I think.  One note, which is that I was getting syntax errors with the nested parentheses. Using curly braces for the inner pair made everything work great.

Comment: wasnt sure about braces though